# Remove an object from an array on a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I have a csv file that I've already splitted by line breaks and I've broken it down even more by the commas in the line breaks to give me three things I'm looking for and named them for later use in the program. What I'm looking to do is remove an item if a one of the objects match a certain value.

```
var values=[];
var output="";
for(i = 0; i < csv_split.length; i++){
    csv_split[i] = csv_split[i].split(',') //Splits the csv file that's already split by new line by commas
                 values[i]={}
    values[i].Name=newline_split[i][1]; //finds the second object and names it values.name
    values[i].Rev=newline_split[i][2]; //finds the third object and names it values.rev
    values[i].URL=newline_split[i][9]; //finds the eighth object and names it values.url
}
```

This then is used later so I can get a list of just the values I'm looking for.

```
for (i=0; i < values.length; i++){
    output += values[i].Name + ',';
    output += values[i].Rev + ',';
    output += values[i].URL+ ',';
    output += "\n\n||||||";
}
```

So what I did was modified this code to the first for loop:

```
if (values[i].Rev == "NO ACCESS") {
    csv_split[i].splice(0,1);
}
```

The idea behind this was that if the values.Rev matched to "NO ACCESS" it would remove the entirety csv_split[i], so that later it wouldn't display it in the output.

Running the script now gives the entire output of regardless if values.Rev matches "NO ACCESS" or not. What am I missing with this?

Comment: You mean to remove the whole CSV line, when the condition is not met?

Comment: I want to remove the entire line of csv_split whenever the condition is met. For example if in csv_split[1] the value of values[1].Rev is equal to "NO ACCESS" I want to remove all the values from csv_split[1] so that later when it is brought up in the second code box it won't show any of the lines where values.Rev = "NO ACCESS"

Answer (score 4):

You could do this much easier with the [filter](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) method.  You use it like this:

```
var finalArr = values.filter(function(val) { return val.Rev != "NO ACCESS"; });
```

This should give you an array of everything that has access.

Comment: I'm working with a 3rd party software that uses a javascript, however it seems that certain functions are not enabled, including the filter function. I can manually create the filter function, however I can't find where the source code for the filter function is.

Is there an online resource for finding the source code for functions already in javascript?

Comment: I don't know of any, but you can try googling.  https://www.javascript.com/ is probably a good place to start.  What are you using that disables built-in functions?

Comment: [Your browser must be at least this tall](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#AutoCompatibilityTable)